# How to fix duplicate output values from URL string coming from PHP switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I use switch to get values and echo them in html menu items, I use switch statement:

```
<?php

$val = '';

switch ($_GET['mi']) {

    case '1';
    $val = 'menu__item--current1';
    break;
    case '2':
    $val = 'menu__item--current2';
    break;

    default:
    $val = '';
    break;
?>
```

here is the html source to output into:

```
<li class="menu__item <?php echo $val; ?>"><a href="about.php" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
<li class="menu__item <?php echo $val; ?>"><a href="services.php" class="menu__link">Services</a></li>
```

the problem is I get the same values in both $val places
it is not switching values but it echos first case in both places!

here is the html output source from https://url?mi=1

```
<li class="menu__item menu__item--current1"><a href="about.php" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
<li class="menu__item menu__item--current1"><a href="services.php" class="menu__link">Services</a></li>
```

Comment: it seems it is the correct behaviour, cause the url does have `mi=1` parameter, so the switch always will go to the `case '1'` part

Comment: Instead of switch just use a counter variable and when you are creating these Li's through loop. Put that counter there

Comment: Instead of using `echo $val;` in both cases, use distinct variables, i.e. `$val_about` and `$val_services` and set them accordingly

Comment: @kerbholz it worked your way, but do I feel it is somehow a work around?! thanks any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark your navigation item as active based on `$_GET['mi']` you could do the following:

Consider using *one* class (`menu__item--active`) instead of one for each link (`menu__item--current1`, `menu__item--current2`...). This makes handling more menu items a little easier since you don't have to create a new class for every menu item.

Then in your navigation/menu you could do:

```
<li class="menu__item<?php if(isset($_GET['mi']) && $_GET['mi'] == 1) { echo ' menu__item--active';} ?>">
<a href="about.php" class="menu__link">About</a>
</li>
<li class="menu__item<?php if(isset($_GET['mi']) && $_GET['mi'] == 2) { echo ' menu__item--active';} ?>">
<a href="services.php" class="menu__link">Services</a>
</li>
```

Comment: so it worked this way without the switch at all, thank you.

Comment: can I use the page name ex: "about.php" instead of "mi" value?

Comment: Would be possible, yes: `<?php if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'about') ...` if you want to use a parameter in your URL.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use any parameter at all something like this could work: `<?php if(basename(__FILE__, '.php') == 'about') ...`

Comment: Yes no need for parameters, but it did not work this way "if(basename...", something wrong... here is the html I used: <li class="menu__item <?php if(basename(__FILE__, '.php') == 'about') { echo 'menu__item--current';} ?>"><a href="about.php" class="menu__link">About</a></li>

Comment: Ok, I assume you have your menu (the `<li>` stuff) in a separate file and include it in `about.php` and `services.php`? If so, `basename(FILE, '.php')` will return the name of that included file. Use `<?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'about') ...` instead. Hope this works. And consider opening a new question next time.